# is it normal for vigorous bubbling in airlock right away?

Tags: airlock

I made a 5 gallon batch of sweet mead last night and when I woke up I heard it bubbling away like crazy! Is this normal if I'm using the s style airlock? First time using this type. It's been bubbling constantly all day at a pretty rapid pace.

Comment: It would be good to know a bit more about how you made the mead. What sort of yeast did you use? How much? And most importantly, what was the temperature of the must (unfermented wine) when you added the yeast?

Answer (score 3):

Perfectly normal. Properly rehydrated dry yeast or a good liquid starter will do this.

Comment: I used lalvin 71b-1122 (2packets) and 8 grams fermaid k nutrient. I properly rehydrated the yeast. Its still bubbling pretty good, with short breaks sometimes. Its been at a stable 72 degrees.

Comment: Just wanted to second Pepi's answer- your yeast probably just hit the ground running! However you rehydrated your yeast, and the pitching rate (amount of yeast compared to your original gravity) must have been right on!